# Typescript optional generics in factory functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm tring to figure how to use typescript generics in my factory function to have the proper type base on optional arguments. The factory function makes an object and should optionally run a function if supplied that sets defaults on the object. Here is a really simple example

```
function model<T>(setDefaults?: (input: T) => Record<string, any>){   
  return {     
    create: (input: T) => {
      return setDefaults ? setDefaults(input) : input     
    }
  } 
}
```

These work but I would like the return type of the create method not to be the basic Record<string, any>

```
const myModel = model<{name: string, count: number, type?: string}>() 

const otherModel = model<{name: string, count: number, type?: string}>((input) => ( {...input, above100: count > 100} ))
```

What can I replace Record<string, any> with as the function return type that would give me a type like this for the otherModel example?

```
{ 
  name: string,   
  count: number,   
  type?: string,   
  above100: boolean 
}
```

I have tried using another generic for the function but I could not figure out how to get that to work. I have read through the documentation a lot also but nothing is clicking. Is what I want possible and if so how do I pull it off?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Normally if you have an optional generic parameter, it makes sense to use a function overload so the function is only generic if you call it with the argument, and then you can use the other overload to specify what the return type will be if you call it without the argument.

Comment: It's not clear to me how this function should behave. What goes wrong if you use a second generic type parameter for the return type of the setDefaults function? `model<T, R>(setDefaults?: (input:T) => R)`

Comment: @StephenJennings I was trying to see if there is a way for typescript to infer that return type of the setDefaults function that is supplied in order to avoid having to specify the return type manually. Not sure if it is possible.